# Number of columns related to results MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

Table 1 - documents:

```
ID    Title
====================
1     doc 1
2     doc 2
3     doc 3
4     doc 4
```

Each document can be assigned to multiple subcategories - this relation resides in table 2.

Table 2 - doc_subcategory which matches document_id and subcategory_id:

```
document_id    subcategory_id
============================
1              1
1              2
1              5
2              1
2              2
3              1     
3              7
4              2
4              3
4              5
```

Table 3 - subcategories - there's also a subcategory table that contains its id, name and higer_level_category_id of another (higher) level of category.

```
id    name           higer_level_category_id      
============================================
1     To buy         1
2     To give back   1
3     To send        1
4     To buy         2
5     To send        2
6     To throw       2
7     To destroy     2
```

What want to get is this:

```
doc_id    doc_title    subcat_id        subcat_id       upper_1  upper_2
                       for_upper_cat1   for_upper_cat2

==========================================================================================
1         doc 1        1,2              5               1        2                        
2         doc 2        1,2              NULL            1        NULL
3         doc 3        1,7              7               1        2
4         doc 4        2,3              5               1        2
```

I created a query that kind, but I've no idea how to separate subcategories and upper categories into separate columns:

```
SELECT
  documents.id as doc_id,
  documents.title as doc_title,
  group_concat(DISTINCT doc_subcategory.subcategory_id) as subcat_id,
  group_concat(DISTINCT subcategories.higer_level_category_id) as upper
FROM 
  documents
LEFT JOIN
  doc_subcategory
  ON
  (
    documents.id = doc_subcategory.id
  ) 
LEFT JOIN
  subcategories
  ON
  (
    doc_subcategory.subcategory_id = subcategories.id
  )
GROUP BY documents.id;
```

I've noticed that when I give another parameter to order by clause which is subcategories.higer_level_category_id this gives me a bit better results, but still this is far from what I want. The problem is with dynamic columns which should be created on the fly that relates to number of subcategories.higer_level_category_id.

Comment: Normally, you'd have access to some kind of application-level code/presentation layer, which is where you would handle these kinds of display issues.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a few errors in your query (e. g. there is no column `doc_subcategory.id`). I put together a little rextester-demo with your query. You can find it here: **http://rextester.com/XOP97169**

I updated your query to

```
SELECT
  documents.id as doc_id,
  documents.title as doc_title,
  group_concat(DISTINCT doc_subcategory.subcategory_id) as subcat_id,
  group_concat(DISTINCT subcategories.higher_level_category_id) as upper
FROM documents
LEFT JOIN doc_subcategory ON documents.id       = doc_subcategory.document_id 
LEFT JOIN subcategories   ON doc_subcategory.subcategory_id = subcategories.id
GROUP BY documents.id;
```

This results in

```
doc_id  doc_title   subcat_id   upper
--------------------------------------
1       doc 1       1,2,5       1,2
2       doc 2       1,2         1,2
3       doc 3       1,7         1,2
4       doc 4       2,3,5       2,3
```

Maybe you can illustrate a few finer points on the basis of this fiddle. But, as @Strawberry already said, the "presentation" of the data should usually be left to your embedding application, be it in JavaScript (node.js), python, c# or php....

Comment: Thanks for updating the query. That's exactly the kind of results I get. As for application, I changed a bit column names and tables so it's more readable. I didn't checked that query before, so a little bug came in the oc_subcategory.id thing. Still I need to have two extra columns on as described above.

Comment: Your column layout `subcat_id_for_upper_cat1, subcat_id_for_upper_cat2,upper_1,  upper_2` seems a little arbitrary to me: there can be any number of document-to-subcategory relationships, yet, you only provide 2 columns. And there can be any number of `higher_level_category_id`s. How do you determine in which of the two "upper"-column you want the higher level id information listed? The current `group_concat()` represents much more the real result: i. e. you get a number of `subcat_id`s and another number of `upper` ids, without assigning them to any fixed columns.

Comment: yes, that's true, there might be number of different "upper" and "sub_cat_id_for_upper_cat" columns. That's the thing. I'd like to have it added dynamically based on results. For example if there's 5 values for "upper" then the query should return 10 extra columns each suffixed by higher_level_category_id.